# What is the problem with this Checkboxes in Angular 14 with Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 14 `"@angular/core": "^14.1.0"` with Angular Material `"@angular/material": "^14.2.7"`

I am using the Table sample with the Checkboxes from the [link](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-selection)

And while implementing in my Angular with Visual Studio Code, I get the output below. Why do I get multiple checkboxes for each row along with the Header row?

[image: Angular Material Table Selection Bug]

**EDIT**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox
        (change)="$event ? toggleAllRows() : null"
        [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
        [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()"
        [aria-label]="checkboxLabel()"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox
        (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
        (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
        [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
        [aria-label]="checkboxLabel(row)"
      >
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>No.</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.position }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Weight</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.weight }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Symbol</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.symbol }}</td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr
    mat-row
    *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
    (click)="selection.toggle(row)"
  ></tr>
</table>
```

There is no `css` for this `Component`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your code , required for further probing

Comment: Can you create a JS fiddle of the same ? Just by looking its tough to answer.

Comment: I'ts looks like related to the .css (see if you have well defined the theme or if your'e importing some of default theme) or because you're not well defined the column:`<ng-container matColumnDef="select">`. See that it's not more than a column name defined in your `displayedColumns` variable, but it's hard to help you without know your code. Fell free to edit your question adding the html code or create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or similar

Comment: Have added Html code for this in the Question. There is no css for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you see the example of your link and open the developer tools of your navigator, select one input with type check-box. You see that have as .css

```
.mdc-checkbox .mdc-checkbox__native-control {
  top: calc((var(--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size) - var(--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size)) / 2);
  right: calc((var(--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size) - var(--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size)) / 2);
  left: calc((var(--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size) - var(--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size)) / 2);
  width: var(--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size);
  height: var(--mdc-checkbox-state-layer-size);
}
.mdc-checkbox__native-control {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: inherit;
}
```

If you remove this .css you see a table like your image.

Remember that when you work with material-angular you should choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme (see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#install-angular-material))

To use a pre-build-theme you can edit your angular.json file and add (e.g. if you use deeppurple-amber.css)

```
`node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css`
```

Or add in styles.css

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** Add this line to your `style.css`

```scss
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

---

I've created a [working stackblitz example myself here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-angular-mat-table-example-c5khg8?file=src%2Fstyles.scss). All `mat` components require you to add a [theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme), this are the pre-built ones:
[image]